# Expandable list with JavaScript in Joomla 2.5

Tags: javascript, joomla, joomla2.5, jstree

I inherited a Joomla 2.5 university site.

There is a page with the university structure that looks like a tree. When the user clicks on one of the items, that item expands and everything else collapses. After a few click you may get this:

- Academic structure

  - Rectorate

    - Rector
    - Vice-Rector of X
    - Vice-Rector of Y

      - John Doe

        - phone
        - mail
    - Vice-Rector of Z
  - Departments
  - Programs
- Administrative structure
- Governance structure

The people who worked on the site made **65 different articles** for every possible expansion of the tree. **Impossible to maintain** auto-generated HTML, zero consistency, every page is misaligned beyond repair.

I will remove all the articles and make one page with an expandable tree. I already made a JSON of the structure and it's less than 1 MB (with the photos) so I will just load it collapsed.

I want people to just edit the JSON and not the article code itself. Therefore I need a script that will apply the correct formatting to different JSON trees. For example, all 'person' nodes should be styled  the same way.

How do I enable JavaScript expandable tree in Joomla 2.5? I only have access to the Joomla admin panel, not the server itself. There's an option in the editor to enable  tags, will that be enough? Are there any gotchas if I just insert some JavaScript into the Joomla article?

What should I use for the project? I was thinking of jQuery with jsTree.

Comment: jstree meets all your requirements - keeping only one sibling expanded is easy to achieve and it supports node types (so you can define common icons, etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Joomla configuration you can disable the standard WYSIWYG editor and insert "raw" HTML - including JS - in any content article, but you will still have issues because by default the content views escape most of the JS content.

I suggest a different way instead.

1. Develop a new Joomla **module** where you put all your custom HTML and JS. You can duplicate and adapt the "mod_custom" module type, or you can follow [this tutorial](https://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:Creating_a_simple_module/Developing_a_Basic_Module).
2. Create an instance of this module from Joomla admin panel (Modules -> New -> YourModuleType) and assign it to a fake position (i.e. "tree").
3. Load the module into your article by writing `{loadposition tree}` in the article content. [More about loadposition](https://docs.joomla.org/How_do_you_put_a_module_inside_an_article%3F).

Et voilà! :-)

I suggest to use a **module** because it's simpler for you to edit it as a developer than a Joomla article; and I suggest to still use an **article** as container because it's easier to link a menu item to it and deal with URL / metadata / etc...

Comment: Wow, thanks for the help! 
I almost got the tree done (JavaScript parsing JSON into HTML with nested Bootstrap collapsible buttons). But I was lost at how to put in it Joomla without setting "no editor" as the default editor for articles and without the editors breaking the HTML. I'll try what you suggested and post my results.

Comment: @TreeGuy happy to hear that!